# Copy worksheet macro stops doing anything when the workbook hits 50 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a workbook that has a number of cover sheets and then a bunch of sheets at the back that are contain a few graphs.  The graph pages are created by copy-pasting one sheet ("MasterFormat") over and over again, changing a few key values each time.

The macro originally used to conk out fairly rapidly with a `Copy Method of Worksheet Class failed` error.  I eventually found how to fix it, from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684 .

The problem is, I've had endless issues with my updated version; mostly that it continues running happily, but doesn't actually copy anything after a while.  Part of why it's happy is that the updated logic includes a few `Set x = y, if x is nothing then`s, which (as far as I know) will only work with errors suppressed, so that's what I've done.  But on the other hand, it stops copying sheets after there are 50 sheets, and gives no explanation (though this may be the mislocation of the `on error goto 0`).

Does anyone know what I should be fixing to make it actually copy all the sheets, not just get bored and stop?

The code is as follows:

```
Sub GenerateSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim oBook As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oBook = Workbooks("SSReport.xls")

    If oBook Is Nothing Then
        Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("SSReport.xls")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Const PairingCount = 63

    Dim Pairings(1 To PairingCount, 1 To 2) As String
    For i = 1 To PairingCount
        Pairings(i, 1) = oBook.Sheets("SSPairings").Rows(i + 1).Cells(1)
        Pairings(i, 2) = oBook.Sheets("SSPairings").Rows(i + 1).Cells(2)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To PairingCount

         If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
            oBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Set oBook = Nothing
            Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("SSReport.xls")
         End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        j = oBook.Worksheets.Count
        SheetName = "P" & Pairings(i, 1) & Pairings(i, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = oBook.Sheets(SheetName)
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=Sheets(j)
            oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat (2)").Name = SheetName
        End If
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 2) = Pairings(i, 1)
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 5) = Pairings(i, 2)
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 8) = "P"
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's run from a meta workbook, which was the suggestion of the KB article I linked to above.  Interestingly, despite the `Open workbook`, it doesn't seem to actually work if the main workbook is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably caused by this line:

```
oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=Sheets(j)
```

The `Sheets(j)` will refer to whichever workbook the code module resides in, which may not be the intended workbook.

The following works for me:

```
Sub GenerateSheets()
Dim oBook As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim SheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Const PairingCount = 63
Dim Pairings(1 To PairingCount, 1 To 2) As String

On Error Resume Next
Set oBook = Workbooks("SSReport.xls")
On Error GoTo 0
If oBook Is Nothing Then
    Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("SSReport.xls")
End If

With oBook
    For i = 1 To PairingCount
        Pairings(i, 1) = .Sheets("SSPairings").Rows(i + 1).Cells(1)
        Pairings(i, 2) = .Sheets("SSPairings").Rows(i + 1).Cells(2)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To PairingCount
        If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
            '//Save in case of corruption/error?'
            .Save
        End If

        j = .Worksheets.Count

        SheetName = "P" & Pairings(i, 1) & Pairings(i, 2)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = .Sheets(SheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            .Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=.Sheets(j)
            .Sheets("MasterFormat (2)").Name = SheetName
        End If

        .Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 2) = Pairings(i, 1)
        .Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 5) = Pairings(i, 2)
        .Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 8) = "P"
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

I took the liberty of replacing the the close/reopen with a simple `Save` as this should achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=Sheets(j)
            oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat (2)").Name = SheetName
        End If
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 2) = Pairings(i, 1)
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 5) = Pairings(i, 2)
        oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 8) = "P"
```

into

```
     If ws Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=Sheets(j)
        oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat (2)").Name = SheetName
    else
       oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 2) = Pairings(i, 1)
       oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 5) = Pairings(i, 2)
       oBook.Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 8) = "P"
    End If
```

I guess if ws is nothing then it stuck in next 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lunatik's answer, I changed `oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=Sheets(j)` to `oBook.Sheets("MasterFormat").Copy After:=oBook.Sheets(j)`, which seemed to fix the problem.